# Facebook app opening in SSL URL once fblogin button is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, sdk, status

I am new in facebook app. Everything's fine until now, when I click the fb login button. 
Normally it will ask me for permission then redirect me to  the actions.php. Now, it will redirect me to the SSL URL outside the facebook canvas. So what I see now is my plain web page not in facebok page anymore.

Here's my index code and my action.php that displays my home page:

**index.php**

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(0);
    include 'library.php';
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>HELP</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
        appId      : '*************', // replace your app id here
        channelUrl : '//<domain_name>/bacardi-test/channel.html',
        status     : true,
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true
        });
    };
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));


        function FBLogin(){
        FB.login(function(response){
            if(response.authResponse){
                window.top.location = "actions.php?action=fblogin";
            }
        }, {scope: 'email,user_likes,user_birthday'});
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <img src="assets/img/bacardi/facebook-connect.png" alt="Fb Connect" title="Login with facebook" onclick="FBLogin();"/>
    </body>
    </html>

actions.php

<?php
include 'library.php';

$action = $_REQUEST["action"];
switch($action){
    case "fblogin":
    include 'src/facebook.php';
    $appid  = "**************";
    $appsecret  = "************";
    $facebook   = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $appid,
        'secret' => $appsecret,
        'cookie' => TRUE,
    ));

    $fbuser = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($fbuser) {
        try {
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit();
        }
        # Account ID
        $user_fbid  = $fbuser;

        # Account Bday
        $user_bday = $user_profile['user_birthday'];

        # Account Email
        $user_email = $user_profile['email'];

        # Account firstname
        $user_fname = $user_profile['first_name'];

        # Account lastname
        $user_lname = $user_profile['last_name'];

        # Accounr image url
        $user_image = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$user_fbid."/picture?type=large";

        $check_select = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email = '$user_email'"));
        if($check_select == 0){
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (fb_id, fname,lname, email, image, birthday,postdate)
            VALUES ('$user_fbid', '$user_fname', '$user_lname', '$user_email', '$user_image', '$user_bday',now())");
        }
    }   
    break;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like window.top.location broke the iframe of facebook.
I was working on automatic prompt of permission rather than Button that I somehow change
it.
Now it's already working. I just changed window.top.location to window.location.href.
Thanks for everyone's time reading my prob.